# Solidity: WETH can't be extracted

Tags: solidity, contract

I can convert ETH to WETH via WETH smart contract and deposit it in my smart contract address, but when I want to convert WETH in my smart contract address to ETH via WETH smart contract and withdraw it to my wallet address, I can't do it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
interface IWETH {
    function deposit() external payable;
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function withdraw(uint256 value) external payable;

}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract testwithdraw {
    uint256 public ETHAnt;
    address public WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;  

    function deposit() public payable{
        ETHAnt = msg.value;      
        IWETH(WETH).deposit.value(ETHAnt)();
    }

    function getContractBalance(address _to) public view returns(uint) {
       uint256 Balance = IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(_to);
       return Balance;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _value) public payable { 
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw.value(_value);
    }
}
```

When using the withdraw function, it tells me that it ran successfully. But I see that the from in the log is actually my wallet address, and the to is my smart contract address. What's going on here?

```
status  true Transaction mined and execution succeed
transaction hash    0x2859b5188b12cb2f0849a26777a5d2d0972e0e2ce000b548b80f3e5ae3b85b32
from    0xAb2942DEcDEa92A43d84DE7097a2e8df373e41Ab
to  testwithdraw.withdraw(uint256) 0xa5f43d3A0C3ee2A99511A14698F0DB082491C751
gas 22323 gas
transaction cost    22323 gas 
hash    0x2859b5188b12cb2f0849a26777a5d2d0972e0e2ce000b548b80f3e5ae3b85b32
input   0x2e1...00000
decoded input   {
    "uint256 _value": "1000000000000000000000"
}
decoded output   - 
logs    []
val 0 wei
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're withdrawing ETH using IWETH(WETH).withdraw.value(_value), it withdraws ETH from WETH contract and stores them on your contract. In order to be able to withdraw received funds, you need to add something like
payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance) in your withdraw function.